# Kotlin split string into range

Tags: arrays, string, kotlin, parsing, range

I need to get a range from string. ; - is a delimeter.

So, for example i have string "10;15;1" and i need to get range from 10 to 15(ignoring the last number).

**Expecting result:**

"10;15;1" -> 10..15

So i tryed to write this code. How can i improove it? it looks bad and innefective

```
val arr = "10;15;1".split(";").dropLast(1).map { it.toBigDecimal() }
val someRange = arr[0] .. arr[1]
```

Comment: Given the pretty specific requirements, I wouldn't say that's bad code at all.  Changes you might consider include seeing whether you could make fewer assumptions about the input format; and handling invalid input better.  Also, if the numbers will always be integers, then `Int` might be simpler than `BigDecimal`.  This looks too specific to be worth splitting out to a separate function, unless you can make it more general somehow.

Comment: The only thing I might suggest is instead of the lambda, putting `map(String::toBigDecimal)` so the code is more self-documenting without losing its conciseness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about validation, you could do this:

```
fun toRange(str: String): IntRange = str
    .split(";")
    .let { (a, b) -> a.toInt()..b.toInt() }

fun main() {
    println(toRange("10;15;1"))
}
```

Output:

```
10..15
```

---

If you want to be more paranoid:

```
fun toRange(str: String): IntRange {
    val split = str.split(";")
    require(split.size >= 2) { "str must contain two integers separated by ;" }

    val (a, b) = split

    return try {
        a.toInt()..b.toInt()
    } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
        throw IllegalArgumentException("str values '$a' and/or '$b' are not integers", e)
    }
}

fun main() {
    try { println(toRange("oops")) } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) { println(e.message) }
    try { println(toRange("foo;bar;baz")) } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) { println(e.message) }
    println(toRange("10;15;1"))
}
```

Output:

```
str must contain two integers separated by ;
str values 'foo' and/or 'bar' are not integers
10..15
```

Answer (score 0):

The function is very specific so it must not exist in the standard library. I have nothing against the implementation although I can suggest alternatives using a Regex and returning a null value if the string is not well formed. But it uses regex.

```kotlin
fun rangeFrom(str: String) : ClosedRange<BigDecimal>? {
    val regex = """^(\d+);(\d+);\d+$""".toRegex()
    val result = regex.find(str)
    return result?.destructured?.let { (fst, snd) ->
        fst.toBigDecimal() .. snd.toBigDecimal()
    }
}
```

Or you can just update your function checking that the length of the list produced by `split` is `>= 2` and directly using `arr[0].toBigDecimal() .. arr[1].toBigDecimal` but it is not very different.